# Webpack image loader not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to get my webpack to transpile my files into a `public/images` directory from the `app/assets/images` but for some reason it is not working. I have used the same script for my font files and all is working fine:

**WORKING**

```
  { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "file-loader?limit=1024&name=fonts/[name].[ext]"
  }
```

But for some reason the minute the files are changed into image ones with the test, nothing happens.

**NOT WORKING**

```
  {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "file-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]"
  }
```

Am I missing something for images?

Comment: My understanding of these loaders is that they are only called if your code actually references a file that matches the test regex.  I assume you have a reference to an image in your code somewhere?